# PIL vs RMagick/ruby-gd

Tags: python, ruby, python-imaging-library, rmagick

For my next project I plan to create images with text and graphics.  I'm comfortable with ruby, but interested in learning python.  I figured this may be a good time because PIL looks like a great library to use.  However, I don't know how it compares to what ruby has to offer (e.g. RMagick and ruby-gd).  From what I can gather PIL had better documentation (does ruby-gd even have a homepage?) and more features. Just wanted  to hear a few opinions to help me decide.

Thanks.

Vince

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagic is a huge library and will do everything under the sun, but many report memory issues with the RMagick variant and I have personally found it to be an overkill for my needs.

As you say ruby-gd is a little thin on the ground when it comes to English documentation....  but GD is a doddle to install on post platforms and there is a little wrapper with some helpful examples called [gruby](http://gruby.sourceforge.jp/index.en.html) thats worth a look. (If you're after alpha transparency make sure you install the latest GD lib)

For overall community blogy help, PIL's the way.

Answer (score 7):

PIL is a good library, use it.  ImageMagic (what RMagick wraps) is a very heavy library that should be avoided if possible.  Its good for doing local processing of images, say, a batch photo editor, but way too processor inefficient for common image manipulation tasks for web.

**EDIT:** In response to the question, PIL supports drawing vector shapes.  It can draw polygons, curves, lines, fills and text.  I've used it in a project to produce rounded alpha corners to PNG images on the fly over the web.  It essentially has most of the drawing features of GDI+ (in Windows) or GTK (in Gnome on Linux).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  Does PIL offer good support for vector graphics? My project entails displaying numerous small pieces of text at rotated at different angles and of different size, and I'm guessing that using a vector-based approach would work best.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

PIL has been around for a long time and is very stable, so it's probably a good candidate for your first Python project.  The PIL documentation includes a helpful [tutorial](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm), which should get you up to speed quickly.

Comment: My original reply was posted 5 years ago.  Currently I would recommend using [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in favor of PIL.